# Speech recognition software application or website for speech-to-text conversion?

Tags: gratis, speech-recognition

**Google** has a good speech recognition engine for different languages (English, Russian, etc.) Recognition errors/inaccuracies are minimal. Sometimes, instead of manually typing the text, I would like to simply dictate it to a program, and it is converted to text on the fly.

The **"OK Google"** voice search allows to recognize and convert to text a speech of a size of **1 sentence** only (roughly). After that searching starts.

Is there a program/application (for Windows) or website (that uses Google speech recognition engine or some good alternative) to input fairly large amounts of text (more than default Google voice search allows). Sometimes it is very necessary. Manual typing sometimes is not suitable or simply tedious due to laziness. It would be easier to dictate everything.

It is for private use only and, as pointed out, not necessarily bound to the Google engine – as long as quality fits. The reason why I give Google example because quality of their services is quite good and at the same time it is free. I was looking for that kind of software or site offering such services for free.

Specifically, I am interested in **Russian** **voice-to-text** conversion tool/website (but Google seem to have good engine for most languages).

My OS: **Windows 10 x64**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://transcribe.wreally.com/guide/how-to-transcribe-semi-automatically-using-dictation/

> "supports several languages including English, Spanish, Portuguese, Dutch, Chinese, French, Hebrew, Italian, Japanese, Korean and **Russian**. If you would like us to add support for another language please let us know."

I have not tried this feature of the software, but I was happy with the other feature of the software, that I did use.